# Rails nokogiri parse XML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm a little bit confused: could not find in web good examples of parsing xml with nokogiri...

example of my data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <rows SessionGUID="6448680D1">
        <row>
            <AnalogueCode>0451103079</AnalogueCode>
            <AnalogueCodeAsIs>0451103079</AnalogueCodeAsIs>
            <AnalogueManufacturerName>BOSCH</AnalogueManufacturerName>
            <AnalogueWeight>0.000</AnalogueWeight>
            <CodeAsIs>OC90</CodeAsIs>
            <DeliveryVariantPriceAKiloForClientDescription />
            <DeliveryVariantPriceAKiloForClientPrice>0.00</DeliveryVariantPriceAKiloForClientPrice>
            <DeliveryVariantPriceNote />
            <PriceListItemDescription />
            <PriceListItemNote />
            <IsAvailability>1</IsAvailability>
            <IsCross>1</IsCross>
            <LotBase>1</LotBase>
            <LotType>1</LotType>
            <ManufacturerName>KNECHT/MAHLE</ManufacturerName>
            <OfferName>MSC-STC-58</OfferName>
            <PeriodMin>2</PeriodMin>
            <PeriodMax>4</PeriodMax>
            <PriceListDiscountCode>31087</PriceListDiscountCode>
            <ProductName>Фильтр масляный</ProductName>
            <Quantity>41</Quantity>
            <SupplierID>30</SupplierID>
            <GroupTitle>Замена</GroupTitle>
            <Price>203.35</Price>
        </row>
        <row>
            <AnalogueCode>0451103079</AnalogueCode>
            <AnalogueCodeAsIs>0451103079</AnalogueCodeAsIs>
            <AnalogueManufacturerName>BOSCH</AnalogueManufacturerName>
            <AnalogueWeight>0.000</AnalogueWeight>
            <CodeAsIs>OC90</CodeAsIs>
            <DeliveryVariantPriceAKiloForClientDescription />
            <DeliveryVariantPriceAKiloForClientPrice>0.00</DeliveryVariantPriceAKiloForClientPrice>
            <DeliveryVariantPriceNote />
            <PriceListItemDescription />
            <PriceListItemNote>[0451103079] Bosch,MTGC@0451103079</PriceListItemNote>
            <IsAvailability>1</IsAvailability>
            <IsCross>1</IsCross>
            <LotBase>1</LotBase>
            <LotType>0</LotType>
            <ManufacturerName>KNECHT/MAHLE</ManufacturerName>
            <OfferName>MSC-STC-1303</OfferName>
            <PeriodMin>3</PeriodMin>
            <PeriodMax>5</PeriodMax>
            <PriceListDiscountCode>102134</PriceListDiscountCode>
            <ProductName>Фильтр масляный</ProductName>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
            <SupplierID>666</SupplierID>
            <GroupTitle>Замена</GroupTitle>
            <Price>172.99</Price>
        </row>
      </rows>
</root>
```

and ruby code:

```
...
xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)
parts = xml_doc.xpath('/root/rows/row')
```

with the help of xpath i could do this? also how to get this parts object (row)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. `parts = xml_doc.xpath('/root/rows/row')` gives you back a `NodeSet` i.e. a list of the `<row>` elements.

You can loop through these using `each` or use row indexes like `parts[0]`, `parts[1]` to access specific rows. You can then get the values of child nodes using `xpath` on the individual rows.

e.g. you could build a list of the `AnalogueCode` for each part with:

```
codes = []
parts.each do |row|
  codes << row.xpath('AnalogueCode').text
end
```

---

Looking at the full example of the XML you're processing there are 2 issues preventing your XPath from matching:

1. the `<root>` tag isn't actually the root element of the XML so `/root/..` doesn't match
2. The XML is using namespaces so you need to include these in your XPaths

so there are a couple of possible solutions:

1. use CSS selectors rather than XPaths (i.e. use `search`) as suggested by [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man)
2. after `xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)` do `xml_doc.remove_namespaces!` and then use `parts = xml_doc.xpath('//root/rows/row')` where the double slash is XPath syntax to locate the `root` node anywhere in the document
3. specify the namespaces:

e.g.

```
xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)
ns = xml_doc.collect_namespaces
parts = xml_doc.xpath('//xmlns:rows/xmlns:row', ns)

codes = []
parts.each do |row|
  codes << xpath('xmlns:AnalogueCode', ns).text
end
```

I would go with 1. or 2. :-)

Comment: hm... seemd that it return 0 or [] just
also how to put it in object?

Comment: Yep, the return value will just be the return from `each`. To build a list of objects you'd have to do that inside the loop. I'll update the example.

Comment: try doing `puts parts.size` for the XML included in your question. It should print "2" (for the 2 rows), if not it sounds like the XML structure you're testing with isn't the same as in your question and your `/rows/rows/row` XPath isn't matching.

Comment: yes you are right, dynamically i get this: could you take a look please? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/demooc90.xml
'/s:Envelope/s:Body/SearchOfferResponse/SearchOfferResult/root/rows' - this didn't work

Comment: any ideas (file is upper)?

Comment: I'd updated the answer with suggestions. Did you read through that?

Comment: i try your solution... on first look didn't work yet

Comment: i figured what's going on: my xml is "escaped" - so it didn't work... will try to find how to unescape it

Answer (score 2):

First, Nokogiri supports XPath *AND* CSS. I recommend using CSS because it's more easily read:

```
doc.search('row')
```

will return a NodeSet of every `<row>` in the document.

The equivalent XPath is:

```
doc.search('//row')
```

> ...how to get this parts object (row)?

I'm not sure what that means, but if you want to access individual elements inside a `<row>`, it's easily done several ways.

If you only want one node inside each of the row nodes:

```
doc.search('row Price').map(&:to_xml)
# => ["<Price>203.35</Price>", "<Price>172.99</Price>"]

doc.search('//row/Price').map(&:to_xml)
# => ["<Price>203.35</Price>", "<Price>172.99</Price>"]
```

If you only want the first such occurrence, use `at`, which is the equivalent of `search(...).first`:

```
doc.at('row Price').to_xml
# => "<Price>203.35</Price>"
```

Typically we want to iterate over a number of blocks and return an array of hashes of the data found:

```
row_hash = doc.search('row').map{ |row|
  {
    AnalogueCode: row.at('AnalogueCode').text,
    Price: row.at('Price').text,
  }
}
row_hash 
# => [{:AnalogueCode=>"0451103079", :Price=>"203.35"},
#     {:AnalogueCode=>"0451103079", :Price=>"172.99"}]
```

These are *ALL* covered in Nokogiri's tutorials and are answered many times here on Stack Overflow, so take the time to read and search.

Comment: could you take a look please? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/demooc90.xml
'/s:Envelope/s:Body/SearchOfferResponse/SearchOfferResult/root/rows' - this didn't work

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Well, you made it look as if there were no namespaces in your input document (by just omitting an important part of the document). But there _is_ a namespace, and most likely you did not register the `s:` prefix in Nokogiri.

Comment: any ideas with new file?