# Read data from xml file using nokogiri (with namespace)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I would like to read xml data (xml data provided below) and put into array of hash below is the program that I did test and I can read nodes of xml but do not know how to get element of

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("data.xml"))
status_group = doc.xpath('//source:HotelRooms/*', 'source' => 'http://example.com')
# this working and I can get the element of the xml below
```

based from above I can get status_group element, 
my question how I read each element data and put into array of hash so I can read the data
I'm following answer from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28886962/938947) but still get an error

```
row_hash = status_group.map{ |row|
  {
    RoomTypeName:  row.at('RoomTypeName').text,
    RoomTax:       row.at('RoomTax').text,
  }
}
```

this data.xml data

```
    <HotelRoomAvailabilityResponse xmlns="http://example.com">
        <Status>
            <StatusCode>01</StatusCode>
            <Description>Successful: AvailableHotelRoom Successful</Description>
        </Status>
        <ResultIndex>1</ResultIndex>
        <HotelRooms>
            <HotelRoom>
                <RoomIndex>1</RoomIndex>
                <RoomTypeName>Superior - Double</RoomTypeName>
                <Inclusion/>
                <RoomTypeCode>x1</RoomTypeCode>
                <RatePlanCode>y1</RatePlanCode>
                <RoomRate IsPackageRate="false" B2CRates="false" AgentMarkUp="0.00" Currency="USD" RoomFare="87.54" RoomTax="18.36" PrefPrice="1412040.00" TotalFare="105.90" PrefCurrency="IDR">
                    <DayRates>
                        <DayRate Date="2018-12-30T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                        <DayRate Date="2018-12-31T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                        <DayRate Date="2019-01-01T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                    </DayRates>
                    <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
                    <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
                    <Discount>0</Discount>
                    <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
                    <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
                </RoomRate>
                <RoomPromtion/>
                <Amenities/>
            </HotelRoom>
            <HotelRoom>
                <RoomIndex>2</RoomIndex>
                <RoomTypeName>Superior - Double</RoomTypeName>
                <Inclusion/>
                <RoomTypeCode>x2</RoomTypeCode>
                <RatePlanCode>y2</RatePlanCode>
                <RoomRate IsPackageRate="false" B2CRates="false" AgentMarkUp="0.00" Currency="USD" RoomFare="87.54" RoomTax="18.36" PrefPrice="1412040.00" TotalFare="105.90" PrefCurrency="IDR">
                    <DayRates>
                        <DayRate Date="2018-12-30T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                        <DayRate Date="2018-12-31T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                        <DayRate Date="2019-01-01T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                    </DayRates>
                    <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
                    <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
                    <Discount>0</Discount>
                    <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
                    <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
                </RoomRate>
                <RoomPromtion/>
                <Amenities/>
            </HotelRoom>
        </HotelRooms>
    </HotelRoomAvailabilityResponse>
```

Comment: I think the problem is there is no node for `RoomTax`, it is an attribute of the `RoomRate` node, right? Can you show the error you receive?

Comment: there is RoomTax if we scroll right, inside <RoomRate IsPackageRate="false" B2CRates="false" AgentMarkUp="0.00" Currency="USD" RoomFare="87.54" RoomTax="18.36"...>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `row.at('RoomTax').text,` to

```
row.at('RoomRate').attribute('RoomTax').text
```

should fix the issue

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("data.xml"))
data_xml = <<-EOT
<HotelRoomAvailabilityResponse xmlns="http://example.com">
    <Status>
        <StatusCode>01</StatusCode>
        <Description>Successful: AvailableHotelRoom Successful</Description>
    </Status>
    <ResultIndex>1</ResultIndex>
    <HotelRooms>
        <HotelRoom>
            <RoomIndex>1</RoomIndex>
            <RoomTypeName>Superior - Double</RoomTypeName>
            <Inclusion/>
            <RoomTypeCode>x1</RoomTypeCode>
            <RatePlanCode>y1</RatePlanCode>
            <RoomRate IsPackageRate="false" B2CRates="false" AgentMarkUp="0.00" Currency="USD" RoomFare="87.54" RoomTax="18.36" PrefPrice="1412040.00" TotalFare="105.90" PrefCurrency="IDR">
                <DayRates>
                    <DayRate Date="2018-12-30T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                    <DayRate Date="2018-12-31T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                    <DayRate Date="2019-01-01T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                </DayRates>
                <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
                <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
                <Discount>0</Discount>
                <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
                <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
            </RoomRate>
            <RoomPromtion/>
            <Amenities/>
        </HotelRoom>
        <HotelRoom>
            <RoomIndex>2</RoomIndex>
            <RoomTypeName>Superior - Double</RoomTypeName>
            <Inclusion/>
            <RoomTypeCode>x2</RoomTypeCode>
            <RatePlanCode>y2</RatePlanCode>
            <RoomRate IsPackageRate="false" B2CRates="false" AgentMarkUp="0.00" Currency="USD" RoomFare="87.54" RoomTax="18.36" PrefPrice="1412040.00" TotalFare="105.90" PrefCurrency="IDR">
                <DayRates>
                    <DayRate Date="2018-12-30T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                    <DayRate Date="2018-12-31T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                    <DayRate Date="2019-01-01T00:00:00" BaseFare="29.17950000"/>
                </DayRates>
                <ExtraGuestCharges>0</ExtraGuestCharges>
                <ChildCharges>0</ChildCharges>
                <Discount>0</Discount>
                <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
                <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
            </RoomRate>
            <RoomPromtion/>
            <Amenities/>
        </HotelRoom>
    </HotelRooms>
</HotelRoomAvailabilityResponse>
EOT
doc = Nokogiri::XML(data_xml)
status_group = doc.xpath('//source:HotelRooms/*', 'source' => 'http://example.com')
row_hash = status_group.map{ |row|
  {
    RoomTypeName:  row.at('RoomTypeName').text,
    RoomTax:       row.at('RoomRate').attribute('RoomTax').text,
  }
}

puts row_hash


#=>
#{:RoomTypeName=>"Superior - Double", :RoomTax=>"18.36"}
#{:RoomTypeName=>"Superior - Double", :RoomTax=>"18.36"}
```

Comment: sorry it's still problem

Comment: I can confirm this works (was just trying the same thing :P )